# FBX option from import is missing

Tags: import

I have a blend file, But when I am trying to import the only options I have are collada and alembic. FBX, OBJ etc are all missing.

I have enabled FBX add on in preferences. I have seen the options MANY times before, why is it missing all of a sudden?

Comment: are you using an old version of Blender?

Comment: Are there any errors displayed on the console?

Comment: Blender 2.8. There are no errors, just when I click file>Import> all I see is collada and alembic. If I open a new blender window, I have all the import options. This file had those options and now they have disappeared

Comment: I would check the User Preferences for _that_ blend file; Addons > Import/Export

Comment: Ive done that. All add ons have been added correctly

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem . 
But i accidentally found a solution so I thought  I should share it. 
The  import export options like . Fbx  etc are missing In layout workspace, if you switch to modeling you will find all the other import export options. 
Same in case of  exporting uv layout, it's missing if you open a window and use uv editor but it's present in uv editing workspace.

Comment: Thanks, i had this problem, is it fix above 2.80 ?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is due to the import add-ons being turned off in the workspace.
The solution is to look into the Properties Editor Panel and select the Context Tab → Workspace → **disable** "Filter Add-ons" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: This is noteworthy and many thanks. I have never known this previously.