# Blender Missing Import Options

Tags: import

I have been working on a Blender project for a couple of days and I want to import another image as plane. I got to File -> Import and only see options for importing "Collada" and "Alembic". How do I get back the other import options?

[image: Blender Import Options Screenshot]

If I make a new project, then all import options are there.

Comment: Could it be that the add-on are [filtered in the workspace](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148159/fbx-option-from-import-is-missing)?

Comment: I had the same problem. I just Reloaded the defaults and all is back again.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I have all Filter Add-ons checked under Workspace. If I uncheck all Add-ons, then the import options come back. Does this mean something is corrupted with the file?

Comment: @LeoNas What do you mean by "reloading the defaults". Is this resetting Blender preferences?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your file, it just means that in the particular workspace some add-ons have been filtered ("hidden").

Comment: Yes. I don't have the Blender here now and I just didn't remember it.

Comment: I'm marking this question as duplicate since disabling the filter solves the problem. [FBX option from import is missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148159/fbx-option-from-import-is-missing)