# I can't see export to .fbx icon

Tags: export

It is just not there. Im new so I don't really know what to do.
There is also no FBX Addon in Preferences.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148159/fbx-option-from-import-is-missing/152725#152725

Comment: It is unchecked tho